# How can we trust second-order logic?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Hello Philosophy Stack Exchange,

This is a question I originally asked on Mathematics Stack Exchange, but was encouraged to ask here. Unfortunately you cannot directly migrate to this site, so the original question is still up.

—

Let’s accept for the sake of argument the ontology of set theories without proper classes. Sets (improper classes) are the only things at all. This is perhaps silly, but it will hopefully illustrate a more general point. If we want to regard predicates as things, then they must be sets. Typically this is done by regarding a predicate as the set of all ordered tuples satisfying it. But this would involve proper classes, so we instead need to model the second order logic of set theory as having a universal set. But this will force the membership relation to be interpreted as something other than itself. So why should we trust anything proven using second order logic when its models might not include “real” universe. Things could conceivably be true in all of them without being true in the real universe. I suppose Lowenheim-Skolem might help, but wouldn’t model theory be infected by the same problem, since models would have to be sets? Sorry if this is unclear, I suppose the broader issue is, how do we know that metamathematics doesn’t force us to give up certain models of theories?

Comment: "predicates as things, then they must be sets" Why? There are objects (particulars) and their properties.

Comment: "can we trust second-order logic?" Why not? If we agree (do we ?) on the existence of properties and abstract objects (numbers, sets) why not quantify over them? The real issue is that, unfortunately, SOL lacks od the beautiful simple features of FOL...

Comment: If regarding predicates as things would involve proper classes why on earth would we accept ontology of set theories without proper classes? If modeling second order logic of set theory as having a universal set leads us to mistrust second order logic why on earth would we model it that way? And since we know that metamathematics *does* force us to give up certain theories because they are silly or incoherent, why ask how we know that it doesn't?

Comment: Predicates must be sets by assuming the ontology of set theory. Again, this is probably silly, but, if we’re supposed to have unlimited set construction, so if you can take a predicate to be all the sets satisfying it, then that looks an awful lot like a set, so our notion of sets can’t have been that unlimited after all.

Comment: Ontology of set theory includes proper classes, the universe of sets is a proper class, etc. You can not take a predicate to be all the sets satisfying it without running into paradoxes, and that is not how predicates are taken in FOL or SOL. Nobody thought that our notion of sets is "unlimited" since Russell and Zermelo, this is why set comprehension is explicitly restricted in ZFC and properties are treated as non-sets (and even non-classes) in SOL.

Comment: @Conifold The ontology of ZFC does not include proper classes, while other theories (I was explicit in discluding them) like NBG and MK do. If you are using the standard proper class modelling of second order logic then predicates are the proper classes of all sets satisfying them (as I said). People reject The Axiom of Constructibility out of the sense that it contradicts unlimited set formation, which is not a synonym for the Axiom of Comprehension. It’s not useful to me if you reject the premise of my question, and please give out accurate information.

Comment: *Vocabulary* of ZFC does not include proper classes, it does not mean that ontology does not, they appear in meta-theory anyway. Properties in SOL are directly quantified over, so there is no need to reduce them to something else, and *predicates* are just linguistic objects even in FOL. Constructibility isn't needed to limit set frormation, Zermelo's axiom already restricts comprehension to a pre-existing set, all ZFC axioms put together do not allow forming (strongly) inaccessible cardinals, etc.